NextJS running out of memory in development mode when uploading image
I created an API route in my project to handle image upload to an AWS S3 bucket. However, whenever I call the route, it tries to compile then runs out of memory and restarts. How do I address this? I'm on NextJS version 14.2.10.

It tries to compile? To compile what, exactly?

@EricMORAND in development mode not all the pages are precompiled, so only when you go to them does nextjs compile. This is the same for any API routes you create i guess.
